# C++: iterate over a list, calling a method that deletes its list member

Tags: c++, c++11, set, unordered-set

Let us say a subscription can be represented as a `string`, perhaps a topic of interest.

My class has `Subscribe()` and `Unsubscribe()` methods taking these strings, and maintaining an `unordered_set` of the strings we're currently subscribed to.

The destructor, for convenience, will `Desubscribe()` from every topic you're currently subscribed to (which, let us say, is necessary for this system).

However the simple loop doesn't work because `Unsubscribe()` is deleting set items.

*Note there are similar questions where the deletion is optional and perhaps done by the method in question.  This question differs because the deletion is done by a different method.*

So what is the clearest way to code this so that it works?

```
unordered_set<string> setsSubscribed;

MyClass::~MyClass() {
    while ( auto it: setsSubscribed )
        Unsubscribe( *it );
}
```

Comment: Please add the c++ tag to C++ questions so that more users will see it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.  Let me know if there's any problem with this, or a clearer way to write it.  I'm no C++ expert but I don't recall seeing this idiom before.

```
MyClass::~MyClass() {
    while ( setsSubscribed.size() )
        Unsubscribe( *setsSubscribed.begin() );
}
```